# Get directory size from WebHDFS?

Tags: webhdfs

I see that webhdfs does not support directory size.  In HDFS, I can use

```
hdfs dfs -du -s -h /my/directory
```

Is there a way to derive this from webHDFS?  I need to do this programmatically, not by viewing the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think WebHDFS's GETCONTENTSUMMARY can provide you the information. More information here: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Get_Content_Summary_of_a_Directory

Here is the schema for GETCONTENTSUMMARY: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#ContentSummary_JSON_Schema

You'll see that it has the filed "spaceConsumed" which is the disk space consumed.

Comment: What is the difference between length and spaceConsumed?

Comment: length is the unreplicated size, spaceConsumed is replicated size